# What is the value of android.os.Build.MODEL on a LG G4 device?

Tags: android, lg

Could someone please confirm what the value of android.os.Build.MODEL is on a LG G4 device?

`Log.v("foobar", android.os.Build.MODEL);`

I can't find the information anywhere...

Comment: I am pretty sure it is VS986 4G.

Comment: Bear in mind that there may be multiple devices known as a G4 (e.g., CDMA vs. GSM). "G4" is a marketing name, not a unique product identifier.

Comment: You are right @CommonsWare , and I thought about that after posting, but I'm trying to think in a pattern that could be common to every G4, but I couldn't find the value to even one of them.